# Hide an element in HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any chance that someone has a solution for this problem, If you look at my Codepen link there will be a text "Johnny" that I want to hide behind the dark grey div. Is there by any chance a simple solution for this? Thanks!

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/eartzz/pen/ExPEpEL)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Johnny Porty</title>

    <!-- LINKED CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">

    <!-- LINKED FONT -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body>

    <nav id="navbar">

        <h1>NOICE</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact <span class="arrow arrow-bottom"></span></a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <div class="first_div">

        <h1> JOHNNY </h1>

    </div>

    <div class="second_div">

        <h1> STONEY </h1>

    </div>
    

    <!-- LINK SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you include also the relevant parts of the `main.css` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly define `position: relative` on `.first_div` AND `.second_div`
and then
Set `z-index:10` on `nav`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {scrollNav()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

function scrollNav() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 1) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

nav{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: none;
    transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
    height: 75px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

    line-height: 75px;

    padding-left: 10%;
    z-index:10;
}

nav h1{
    display: inline;

    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;

    margin-right: 20%;
}

nav ul{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav li{
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 2.5%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

nav a{
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
    color: #212121;
}

.sticky {
    background-color: white;
}


.first_div{
    background: url(../img/wide_mount.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: 75% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 75% auto;
    -o-background-size: 75% auto;
    background-size: 75% auto;

    height: 95vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

}

.first_div h1{
    color: rgb(199, 132, 45);
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    letter-spacing: 10vw;

    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    font-size: 128px;
    word-break: break-all;

    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;

    z-index: 3;


}

.first_div h1::selection{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(199, 132, 45);
}

.second_div{
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: #212121;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;

}

.second_div h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Johnny Porty</title>

    <!-- LINKED CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">

    <!-- LINKED FONT -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body>

    <nav id="navbar">

        <h1>NOICE</h1>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact <span class="arrow arrow-bottom"></span></a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>

    <div class="first_div">

        <h1> JOHNNY </h1>

    </div>

    <div class="second_div">

        <h1> STONEY </h1>

    </div>
    

    <!-- LINK SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` won't work without explicit positioning. Set `position: relative` on `.first_div` and `.second_div` to make your current code work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure about whether its what you wanted, but you can try to replace you css code with

```
    html, body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

    nav{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: none;
    transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
    height: 75px;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;

    line-height: 75px;

    padding-left: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav h1{
    display: inline;

    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;

    margin-right: 20%;
}

nav ul{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav li{
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 2.5%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

nav a{
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
    color: #212121;
}

.sticky {
    background-color: white;
}


.first_div{
    background: url(../img/wide_mount.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: 75% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 75% auto;
    -o-background-size: 75% auto;
    background-size: 75% auto;

    height: 95vh;
    width: 100%;

    z-index: 2;

}

.first_div h1{
    color: rgb(199, 132, 45);
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    letter-spacing: 10vw;

    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    font-size: 128px;
    word-break: break-all;

    user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;

    z-index: 2;


}

.first_div h1::selection{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(199, 132, 45);
}

.second_div{
    position: absolute;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: #212121;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  width: 100%;

    z-index: 4;

}

.second_div h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```